# Can I use Swimlane Rows on AzureDEVOPS Project Board for reporting?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

How many swimlane rows can be created on Azure DevOPS Project Board? From my testing, Azure did not allow me to open in excess of 7 rows. Is this the limit? I would like to open a Swimlane row for each initiative.

Can reporting be done based on the Swimlane Titles?

Answer (score 0):

A query can be run to identify work items in a Board swimlane using the `Board Lane` field. You can find examples in the [Microsoft documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-workflow-changes?view=azure-devops#kanban_query_fields).

Regarding the number of swimlanes that can be created per Board, I have been able to create over 20 swimlanes and I am using the regular AzureDevOps cloud instance. I expect it is possible that some on-prem instances have some different limitations.